# C# MVC 3 / jQuery Preview button CMS

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, http-post

I'm developing a new website for my employer which contains a lot of CMS-style features. One of them is being able to create pages, specify URLs, menus, etc.

This is all fine.

What I'm after is a way to create a "Preview" button on these pages, that does not write to the database. I want to post (preferably the entire Model, if not, just the form data) to a new window and have that view render the page.

I have searched high and low and I cannot find an example that makes sense. Most people seem to have given up :/

I've attempted this by myself with TempData, however TempData gets cleared before I can render the page (as there is more than 2 steps involved from what I can deduce..).

I must POST as the form data will contain HTML (inside a Telerik Editor control).

Does anyone have any idea on a nice way to accomplish this? Or can anyone provide links to some resources? (I've come up completely blank!)

Regards,

chem

Comment: You should go through some of your questions and mark the answers. Other people will find this useful

Comment: Will do. Apologies, I've only started really using SO properly recently :)

Comment: Ha-ha no worries just noticed my percentage is running a bit low too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use TempData. At first step you need explicitly tell leave value in Session, for example:

```
string messageValue = (string) TempData.Peek("message"); // Does not cause ejection
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the model in Session State.

Answer (score 1):

I would store the data in session state.

this may be useful: 
http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2011/02/09/SessionLessControllersMvc3.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could serialize the model to XML and then the action method for the preview page could deserialize it.

See [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys/gals.

I managed to use TempData.

I basically ajax post to an action that stores the content in TempData using a Guid as the key. The Guid is returned and once the ajax post returns a hidden form with a target="_blank" action posts to a Preview action method passing through the Guid. That preview action then renders the view with the content in TempData.

Thanks for the suggestions.. it got me thinking!

Regards,

chem